# C# printing issue - printing datagridview data - 2,3,4 times the printing slowing down --Windows Form

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, printing, datagridview

I fill up a `datagridview` and after that I print out the list from there some extra fix string fields. The first two printing finishing fast but after that 3-4 is slowing down very much(sometimes it freezing).

I think some buffer or something fills up and i have to empty it but how? If I tried to print via pdf printer the first file size is normal ~200KB second is 1MB and the third is 4-6MB the fourth is so big it is freezing.

It is only one page maximum two page long list. Can someone help me to find the problem and offer a solution or more?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        printDocument1.Print();
}
```

Print button

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
        Bitmap bmp = Properties.Resources.ugro;
        Image newImage = bmp;
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, 700, 20, 100, 100);

        Bitmap bmp1 = Properties.Resources.line_1;
        Image newImage1 = bmp1;
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage1, 20, 80, 700, 1);



        e.Graphics.DrawString("Text", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(280, 20));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(lbl_datum.Text, new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(20, 20));
        // e.Graphics.DrawString("Text:", new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(20, 100));

        //e.Graphics.DrawString(txt_BID.Text, new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(160, 80));
        //e.Graphics.DrawString(txt_ID.Text, new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(160, 100));

        DataGridViewCell cell = null;

        foreach (DataGridViewCell selectedCell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
        {
            cell = selectedCell;
            break;
        }

        if (cell != null)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = cell.OwningRow;

        }

        e.Graphics.DrawString("Name", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(40, 60));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Height(cm)", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(150, 60));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Weight(kg)", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(280, 60));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Text(cm)", new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(410, 60));

        int height = 0;
        //int width = 0;

        //e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.DarkGray,new Rectangle(100,100,dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width,dataGridView1.Rows[0].Height));

        //  e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText.ToString(), new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Rectangle(420, 80, dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width,dataGridView1.Rows[1].Height));
        height = 80;

        while (i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count)
        {
            if (height > e.MarginBounds.Height)
            {
                e.HasMorePages = true;
                return;
            }

            height += 20;

            //e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString(), dataGridView1.Font, Brushes.Black, new Rectangle(20, height, dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width, 20));

            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString(), dataGridView1.Font, Brushes.Black, new Rectangle(20, height, dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width+50, 40));

            string sign = String.Format("_____________");

            e.Graphics.DrawString(sign, dataGridView1.Font, Brushes.Black, new Rectangle(150, height, dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width + 100, 40));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(sign, dataGridView1.Font, Brushes.Black, new Rectangle(280, height, dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width + 100, 40));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(sign, dataGridView1.Font, Brushes.Black, new Rectangle(410, height, dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width + 100, 40));

            i++;

            printDocument1.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument1_PrintPage);
        }

        i = 0;
}
```

Which variable is causing my problem?

Comment: marc_s Thx for editing!

Comment: The solution is too simple or no one have the same problem? Or i dont know?!